# Why is my SELECT repeating with dataGrid?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
 public static DataSet selectStudent()
 {
      MySqlConnection conn = connection();
      conn.Open();
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT person.*, student.gradePointAverage, student.majorField FROM person JOIN student", conn);
      MySqlCommandBuilder sqlCmd = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adap);
      DataSet sqlSet = new DataSet();
      adap.Fill (sqlSet, "studentInfo");
      conn.Close();
      return sqlSet;
 }
```

and the button:

```
 private void btnAdminStudentView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    DataSet ds = studentHelperClass.selectStudent();
    dataGridStudent.DataSource = ds.Tables["studentInfo"];
 }
```

why would this be giving me a result like this on the button click?

[image]

Comment: Possibly because of the join conditions (or lack of)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query produces cartesian product because you failed to define how the records are related with each other. You need to add a condition,

```
SELECT person.*, student.gradePointAverage, student.majorField 
FROM person JOIN student
     ON person.ID = student.ID  // example only
```

this means that records from table `person` are related with `ID` on table `student`.

To further gain more knowledge about joins, visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Will give right answer in 10 minutes.